# Display an image of the same name as a selected item in listbox in a picturebox

Tags: .net, vb.net

So im doing a program that the users will be able to add tv shows and they could download images and assign it themselves from within the program. I have a listbox called lstShows and a picturebox called picbox, the problem i have is I don't know how to make the selected item in lstShows to search the directory in Documents for the picture with the same name as the item and then display it in the PicBox. so for example, the user adds Game of Thrones to the lstshows, and then downloads an image for it called "Game of Thrones.jpeg" i wan the lstshows selected item to search for that name and display it under the selected item name, which will be "Game of Thrones". [https://www.dropbox.com/s/50r6n5vy45urobk/SHOWBOXXXX.PNG?dl=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnBwC.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a forum where you can get help with **specific** programming-related problems (such as errors, or problems with your code not working as it should). This forum should not be considered a "code writing"-service nor a "help me find this resource"-service. If you want help please show us what you've tried so far, and explain what is not working and what you want the outcome to be. -- It is also recommended that you read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this perfectly so you should check for any misspelling but I am confident enough about the general layout

```
Dim file_name As String = "C:\users\....\documents"
    file_name = file_name + "\"+ lstshows.value+ ".jpg"
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(file_name)
    picBox.Image = bm
    picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
```

Replace the filename string with wherever the director you want the pictures to be chosen from. And Ensure all pictures are in jpg (or change the .jpg part to whatever you want your pictures to be!)
SizeMode Auto-size is there to ensure the image gets the best possible look for the box (stretch/etc)

Also ensure to put the event as the change event instead of the load!

Comment: You would want to put this code  in a button click or selectbox change event.

Comment: Private Sub frmShowBox_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If Not IO.Directory.Exists(dataDir) Then
            IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dataDir)
        End If

        Dim file_name As String = dataDir

        file_name = file_name + "\" + lstShows.SelectedItem + ".jpeg"

        Dim bm As New Bitmap(file_name)

        Picbox.Image = bm

i done that code, but the program is not running

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/50r6n5vy45urobk/SHOWBOXXXX.PNG?dl=0]

Comment: You have put it on the Load event. Put it in the ShowBox Change event.

Comment: OMG, i have been searching for weeks to do what you done in seconds, thanks alot, now it works, thank you so much.

Comment: @Yousi : If it worked, you should mark his answer as accepted by pressing the check mark on its left.

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle hi, i have another problem, i posted a question on here aswell, but non seems to answer it correctly, here is my other question, if you will, could you please help me with the code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553644/selecting-an-item-from-a-listbox-to-show-more-items-in-another-listbox?noredirect=1#comment64515196_38553644