# Selecting an item from a listbox to show more items in another listbox?

Tags: listbox, checkedlistbox

Alright, so i have a problem with my programming, i have three checkedlistboxes, one called "**lstShows**" 2nd is called "**lstSeasons**" and third is called "**lstEpisodes**" and i have two comboboxes that have seasons and episodes in them, one combobox is called "**cbSeasons**" and 2nd is called "**cbEpisodes**. so what i'm trying to do is, when i press on an item in *lstshows*, i want to be able to assign to it items from *lstSeasons*, and when i want to click on an item in seasons i want to be able to assign items to it in *lstepisodes*

So for example lets say, a tv shows contains 10 seasons, so i add that tv shows and assign 10 seasons for it, then season 1, has 20 episodes, and seasons 2 has 15 episodes, i want to be able to add items to each different show, and season. i have been looking every where but i could not find anything.

Here is the layout https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6xc3sb43ksq8qr/Capture.PNG?dl=0

and i tried to do the code, i done this but it does not work.

```
Dim item As String = lstSeasons.SelectedItem
    lstEpisodes.Items.Add(item)
```

I really need help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you stuck trying to add ListItems from lstSeasons to cbSeasons?

Comment: Is lstShows the .Name property or the .Caption property, If it's .Name try `IstShows.AddItem [Item]` otherwise `ListBox1.AddItem [Item]` should do it. ´ListBox1` ist of course only an example.

Comment: that is not what i want, what i want is, so i add a new show to a list box, and then assign seasons to the selected Item from lstShow, and then lets say i have another show that i added, and then when i press on that show, i want to add different seasons to that selected item from lstshows. so like when i switch between the shows, the seasons items and episod items change aswell acordingly to that show.

Comment: Are you coding in vb.net or vba?

Comment: Im coding in vba windows forms.

Comment: Why do you need Both ComboBox and ListBox for Seasons and Episodes? You can simply just change the `RowSource` of *lstSeasons* when *lstShows* clicked, and change the `RowSource` of *lstEpisodes* when *lstSeasons* clicked. The hard thing is, when you switch between Seasons/Shows, do you want pre-selected items to remain ticked.

Comment: yes i want preselected items to remain clicked, and to show different episodes for each season that is selected, i dont know how to do that, can you help me please. ill explain what i want.

Comment: yes i want preselected items to remain clicked, and to show different episodes for each season that is selected.

so first thing's first, i want to add multiple tv shows in lstshows, and then when a show is selected i want to assign seasons to that shows from lstshows, and i want to assign for each selecteditem in lstseasons the episodes that the season contains, for example, season 1 contains 15 episodes, then i press on season 2, and i want to show lets say 20 episods for season 2/

Pic of layout https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6xc3sb43ksq8qr/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: _"I'm coding in vba windows forms"_: but _checkedlistbox_ control isn't, to my knowledge, available for VBA while it is for Visual Basic (.NET). If you confirm that please remove the VBA tag or state you want to migrate to VBA.

Comment: @user3598756 can you please help me with the code, and im sure its VBA, because it is a school project and we only learn vba at school.

Comment: show your code so that we can see what controls you're actually using and where are you stuck

Comment: @user3598756
I dont know how to make the code for that, im trying to do a program for my school project that will allow the user to add tv shows of their choices and add seasons and episodes manually. i have done everything for it except the listbox thing.
a pic of the program. https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6xc3sb43ksq8qr/Capture.PNG?dl=0

you see lstSeasons, lstshows and lstepisodes. 

what i want to do is, when the user adds a tv show of their choice, i want to be able to, add mutiple tv shows and connect seasons and episodes to that tv show, so for example, i add 2 tv shows---->

Comment: @user3598756
i add 2 tv shows lets say, and then i want to select the first one, when the selecteditem in lstshows is selected then i want to be able to add seasons to that selected item, and when a season is selected from lstSeasons, i want to be able to assign episodes to the selecteditem from lstSeasons. 

and so on and so on, so if i have 20 tv shows in lstShows, i want to be able to assign differnt seasons and episodes to every item, so when i go to a different tv show selecteditem, then that particular tv shows season and episodes will appear.

Comment: _"I have done everything for it except the listbox thing"_: post your code till now

Comment: @user3598756do  you want my Whole code?

Comment: @user3598756

 i put it in a txtFile. Take a look. https://www.dropbox.com/s/73hl3a1cycdk1jn/CODE.txt?dl=0

Comment: your code starts with `Imports System.IO` -> it's VB.NET, no VBA. I'm taking VBA tag off

Comment: @user3598756 alright, im not really that experienced so forgive my mistake, buy did you see my code, and are you able to help me with what i want to achieve? if you want i could send you the whole program in a zip file. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm not used to VB.NET and neither willing to be! (I'd prefer switch to C#). As for a _"not really that experienced"_ coder your code looks quite long and complex to me: did you actually coded it or made a copy&paste form somewhere?

Comment: @user3598756 Im currently in year 12, and this is my first year on vb.net, i coded everything from scratch, except for the saving and importing functions. do you think that it is possible to do what i want to do with the checkedlistboxes or not? if you know someone that could help me please tell me.i really need to do this because the whole project is due on this friday. 

 Thank you.

Comment: I think it's possible. I know no one. Best luck!

Comment: @user3598756 alright, thanks for trying to help, as long as there is hope that it is possible, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your data must be stored somewhere.
For example, you can have one worksheet per show, have the seasons in column A and for each season have the episodes in the same row (starting at column B). If you don't want this data to be seen, just hide the sheets.

So if I understood correctly, first you want to select a show, then the seasons of this show appear in the 2nd listbox, and then when you select a season the episodes of this season appear in the 3rd listbox.

First, you need to add all you shows to the 1st listbox. Here, I'll assume that you have 10 shows, that their corresponding worksheets are Worksheets(1) to Worksheets(10), and that the name of the worksheet is the name of the show (but you can do as you wish, for example storing the show's name in a particular cell).

```
    Dim showName as String
    For i = 1 To 10
       showName = Worksheets(i).Name
       lstShows.AddItem showName
    Next i
```

Then, to get the seasons listbox to change when you select a particular show, you can do this :

```
Private Sub lstShows_Change()

Call Me.lstSeasons.Clear

showName = Me.lstShows.Value
Dim sh as Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(showName)
rowCount = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To rowCount
       Me.lstSeasons.AddItem sh.Cells(i,1).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

And to get the episodes listbox to change when you select a particular season, you can do this :

```
Private Sub lstSeasons_Change()

Call Me.lstEpisodes.Clear

showName = Me.lstShows.Value
Dim sh as Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(showName)
rowCount = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim colCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

    For i = 1 To rowCount
       If Me.lstSeasons.Value = sh.Cells(i,1).Value Then
          colCount = sh.Cells(i, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
          For j = 2 To colCount
             Me.lstEpisodes.AddItem sh.Cells(i,j).Value
          Next j              
    Next i

End Sub
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: the code is showing all red underlines, and im using a checked listbox, the code is not working. but thanks for trying to help, if you can, please look at this image, try to replicate what i have and write up a code that works on the program that you replicated. here is my layout with the names.    https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=Capture.PNG

Answer (score 0):

First thing I believe you need to do is to put a multi dimensional array to store your information.
More details about jagged arrays: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhhsz9t(v=vs.90).aspx

so you can use it this way for example:

```
Dim shows(50)(50) As string
```

This will give you 50 "shows" with 50 episodes each. now you can change those using the program as needed.

Now into the next part which is inserting those in. You can modify them by assigning a value by

```
 shows(1)(12) = "ep12nameofshow1"
```

Where you can assign the string as a variable if you want to be able to manually change the name during runtime

Now you want to add the items to your listbox! So lets go over that with a great little for-loop

```
For Each episode As String In shows(1) 'show number here
    lstEpisodes.Items.Add(episode)
Next
```

please note that I didn't test this since I don't have access to most of your code so please inform me if there are any problems you are facing.

**Update** This code should be working:

1- Add this at top of your page (below class declaration)

```
Dim showEpisodes(99)(99)() As String
```

think of it as showEpisodes(Show#,Season#,Ep#)

2- Add values to your array. How you do that is up to you (use a file, database or just predetermined values. You can even put them in run time. But that's another thing for another question!)

3- Add this part to your season's code

```
For Each element As String In showEpisodes(lstShows.SelectedIndex)(lstSeasons.SelectedIndex)
    lstEpisodes.Items.Add(element)
Next
```

Comment: hi zaid, thank you for trying to help, but that code is not working for some reason, if you want i can give you the program and you can test the right code in real time, i tried and looked everywhere, but i think you are the closes to what i need. 

Here is the program, please try it on that: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vavoey39bbgahqk/SHOWBOX.rar?dl=0

Comment: I can check it for you tonight. I am a little busy right now. But I promise you to check it tonight!

Comment: thanks alot zaid, and if you get it working you are my hero and a legend. thanks again.

Comment: did you find the solution for it? because i really need it. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please check it and try the code already, i really need it for my school project.

Comment: was really busy this weekend. Will see. Sorry!

Comment: It is alright, but please dont forget me, this is the last step and then i finish my project, thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: I skimmed through the code and there are 2 problems first of all: 1- If you want to upload a project please upload the complete project file. Else it makes it a little harder and 2- I can't find where your "add episode" code should happen at. Clarify that and which fields are used to specify season/episode name/etc so I can get on with the solution

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8bmc9684dd3bdc/Show%20Box%201.0.rar?dl=0

the full programme is in that link.

Alright so let me clarify. see in this pic [https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6xc3sb43ksq8qr/Capture.PNG?dl=0] i want to be able to assign different season to every show added in lstShows, and different episodes added in lstEpisodes, i want the user to be able to add them by using the provided dropboxes that u see above lstEpisodes and lstSeasons. So lets say the user adds 3 tv shows, i want every tv show to have different episodes and seasons assigned to it by the user. ty

Comment: gotcha. Give me a few hours to go over everything :)

Comment: So the list of episodes will be pre set and the user will "select' from that list to add it. Am I getting this right? So user selects item from listbox shows which should give him all episodes inside that show (predefined) and he will pick from those episodes. If this is it (I want a confirmation) then we probably got it :)

Comment: Check out the update to the answer. Tell me if it works!

Comment: hi zaid, when i dim the showEpisodes at the top it is showing me an error, can you please try it on the project file i sent you, and what you said is correct, i want to be able to assign seasons to selecteditem in lstshows, and episodes to selecteditem in lstSeasons, so when i select diffrent shows and seasons, the particular assigned items will show in listboxes. 

i really appreciate your help, so if you can, please try the code on the actual project file. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8bmc9684dd3bdc/Show%20Box%201.0.rar?dl=0] 

thank you so much

Comment: Were you able to do it, because i actually tried everything and i didnt manage to do it, now im stuck only on this. Please try.